# Can DC voltage on a DC relay switch an AC circuit?

Tags: relay, dc

Can I use a DC relay with 5VDC to switch a 120V highpowered circuit?

Thanks

Comment: A link to the specific part is often helpful. Especially since the coil and load voltages often differ. Welcome to StackExchagne.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's an entirely common scenario.

Typically, the contact current and voltage rating will actually be higher for AC loads, because the AC waveform passing through zero will quench any arc that forms as the contact breaks.

Check the ratings on the relay you choose to be sure they support your load.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as you respect the ratings of the relays you use. You'll need to make sure that you find a relay with a 5VDC coil voltage, and a high enough rating for the contact voltage and current.

For example, [this relay](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/omron-electronics-inc-emc-div/G5LE-1A4-DC5/Z3116-ND/369019) would be appropriate for a load that draws up to 10 amps of current for a resistive load, and up to 5A of current for a reactive load with power factor 0.4. If you can tell us more about your load (including its current and power factor) then it will be easier to give a more precise recommendation for search criteria or even a part.

You'll also need to make sure that whatever is supplying the 5VDC coil voltage can source enough current, and handle the voltage spikes that arise when the relay is turned off (inductive kickback). For example, the relay I gave above would not be appropriate to drive from the pin of an Arduino, since it's not capable of withstanding the inductive kickback, and cannot source the 80mA necessary for the coil. You may need to use an additional transistor (to switch the coil on and off) and a diode (to absorb the kickback).